# niceframe border gets cut when the content spans multiple pages

Tags: framed

I am trying to dress up my pages with curlyframe of `niceframe` but is seems that it cannot support multiple pages. Am I missing some option for that?

Can I place the curly lines at the edges of every page without having to wrap it around the content?

Where can I find the `niceframe` documentation, so I can figure out the rest frames it supports?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

% twoside, openright
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% removes numbering of sectioning units

\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{niceframe}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}


\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\linespread{1.05} 

\title{A book title}   
\author{xxx} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\curlyframe{
    \begin{center}
    \Huge დედის  ამაგს
    \end{center}

    \settowidth{\versewidth}{ბოროტსა  სძლევს.}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    დედის  ამაგს,\\
    დედის  ვარამს.\\
    ვერ  გაიგებს,\\
    შვილი  მანამ,\\
    სანამ  დედა\\
    ცოცხალია,\\
    თავის  გრძნობებს,\\
    გულში  მალავს.\\
    ვით  მებაღე\\
    ნერგის  ნაზარდს,\\
    შეჰხარის  და\\
    აწევს  ჯაფას.\\
    დედის  გულიც\\
    ასე  არის,\\
    ელოდება,\\
    შვილის  გაზრდას.\\
    რა  წვალებით,\\
    გაგვზრდის  დედა.\\
    ვით  მერცხალი,\\
    თავის  ბარტყებს.\\
    შემოგვისხავს,\\
    ცივ  ზამთარში.\\
    თბილ  ბუხართან,\\
    თავის  ანცებს.\\
    მოგვიყვება,\\
    წითელქუდას.\\
    ამირანის,\\
    გმირულ  ამბებს.\\
    რომ   კეთილი,\\
    ბოროტსა  სძლევს.\\
    და  სიკეთე,\\
    გულს  არ  ავნებს.\\
    იქ  ბუნება,\\
    ვერ  უშველის.\\
    თუ  მშობელი,\\
    აღზრდას  აკლებს.\\
    თუ  პატარა,\\
    ვერ  გაზარდე.\\
    დიდობაში,\\
    შენვე  გავნებს.\\

        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---ვუძღვნი  ყველა  დედას,  პირველ  რიგში  ჩემ  საკუთარ  დედას.}
    \end{verse}

}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things can be made colorful and fancy with `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`. Here is a sample with `pgfornament` and `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false,dvipsnames]{scrbook}

% twoside, openright
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% removes numbering of sectioning units

%\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\usepackage{niceframe}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}


\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\linespread{1.05}

\title{A book title}
\author{xxx}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{%
  colback=white,
  %width=\linewidth/2, Change the width
  left=0pt, % left space between content text and box
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  skin=freelance,
  breakable,
  frame code={%
        \node[anchor=north west,color=Maroon,shift={(0.2cm,0.8cm)}] at (frame.north west)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
        \node[anchor=north east,color=Maroon,shift={(-0.2cm,0.8cm)}] at (frame.north east)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
        \node[anchor=south west,color=Maroon,shift={(0.2cm,-0.9cm)}] at (frame.south west)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
        \node[anchor=south east,color=Maroon,shift={(-0.2cm,-0.9cm)}] at (frame.south east)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
  },
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\begin{mybox}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge დედის  ამაგს
    \end{center}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{ბოროტსა  სძლევს.}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    დედის  ამაგს,\\
    დედის  ვარამს.\\
    ვერ  გაიგებს,\\
    შვილი  მანამ,\\
    სანამ  დედა\\
    ცოცხალია,\\
    თავის  გრძნობებს,\\
    გულში  მალავს.\\
    ვით  მებაღე\\
    ნერგის  ნაზარდს,\\
    შეჰხარის  და\\
    აწევს  ჯაფას.\\
    დედის  გულიც\\
    ასე  არის,\\
    ელოდება,\\
    შვილის  გაზრდას.\\
    რა  წვალებით,\\
    გაგვზრდის  დედა.\\
    ვით  მერცხალი,\\
    თავის  ბარტყებს.\\
    შემოგვისხავს,\\
    ცივ  ზამთარში.\\
    თბილ  ბუხართან,\\
    თავის  ანცებს.\\
    მოგვიყვება,\\
    წითელქუდას.\\
    ამირანის,\\
    გმირულ  ამბებს.\\
    რომ   კეთილი,\\
    ბოროტსა  სძლევს.\\
    და  სიკეთე,\\
    გულს  არ  ავნებს.\\
    იქ  ბუნება,\\
    ვერ  უშველის.\\
    თუ  მშობელი,\\
    აღზრდას  აკლებს.\\
    თუ  პატარა,\\
    ვერ  გაზარდე.\\
    დიდობაში,\\
    შენვე  გავნებს.\\[0.5cm]
    \hspace*{\fill} ---ვუძღვნი  ყველა  დედას,\\
    \hspace*{\fill} პირველ  რიგში  ჩემ \\
    \hspace*{1.75cm}საკუთარ  დედას.\null \hfil
    \end{verse}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variation:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false,dvipsnames]{scrbook}

% twoside, openright
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% removes numbering of sectioning units

%\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\usepackage{niceframe}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}


\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\linespread{1.05}

\title{A book title}
\author{xxx}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{%
  colback=Maroon!10!white,
  width=\linewidth/1, %% Change the width
  left=0pt, % left space between content text and box
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  arc=1cm,
  skin=freelance,
  breakable,
  frame code={%
        \node[anchor=north west,color=Maroon,shift={(-1cm,0.9cm)}] at (frame.north west)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
        \node[anchor=north east,color=Maroon,shift={(1cm,0.9cm)}] at (frame.north east)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
        \node[anchor=south west,color=Maroon,shift={(-1cm,-0.9cm)}] at (frame.south west)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
        \node[anchor=south east,color=Maroon,shift={(1cm,-0.9cm)}] at (frame.south east)
                {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
  },
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\begin{mybox}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge დედის  ამაგს
    \end{center}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{ბოროტსა  სძლევს.}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    დედის  ამაგს,\\
    დედის  ვარამს.\\
    ვერ  გაიგებს,\\
    შვილი  მანამ,\\
    სანამ  დედა\\
    ცოცხალია,\\
    თავის  გრძნობებს,\\
    გულში  მალავს.\\
    ვით  მებაღე\\
    ნერგის  ნაზარდს,\\
    შეჰხარის  და\\
    აწევს  ჯაფას.\\
    დედის  გულიც\\
    ასე  არის,\\
    ელოდება,\\
    შვილის  გაზრდას.\\
    რა  წვალებით,\\
    გაგვზრდის  დედა.\\
    ვით  მერცხალი,\\
    თავის  ბარტყებს.\\
    შემოგვისხავს,\\
    ცივ  ზამთარში.\\
    თბილ  ბუხართან,\\
    თავის  ანცებს.\\
    მოგვიყვება,\\
    წითელქუდას.\\
    ამირანის,\\
    გმირულ  ამბებს.\\
    რომ   კეთილი,\\
    ბოროტსა  სძლევს.\\
    და  სიკეთე,\\
    გულს  არ  ავნებს.\\
    იქ  ბუნება,\\
    ვერ  უშველის.\\
    თუ  მშობელი,\\
    აღზრდას  აკლებს.\\
    თუ  პატარა,\\
    ვერ  გაზარდე.\\
    დიდობაში,\\
    შენვე  გავნებს.\\[0.5cm]

        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---ვუძღვნი  ყველა  დედას,  პირველ  რიგში  ჩემ  საკუთარ  დედას.}
    \end{verse}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And another option using `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false,dvipsnames]{scrbook}

% twoside, openright
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% removes numbering of sectioning units

%\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\usepackage{niceframe}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}


\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\linespread{1.05}

\title{A book title}
\author{xxx}
\date{\today}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newmdenv[%
  hidealllines=true,
  innertopmargin=1cm,
  innerbottommargin=2cm,
  firstextra={%
    \node[anchor=north west] 
      at (O|-P) {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm]{35}};
    \node[anchor=north east] 
      at (P)  {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm]{36}};
  },
  singleextra={%
    \node[anchor=north west] 
      at (O|-P) {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm]{35}};
    \node[anchor=north east] 
      at (P)  {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm]{36}};
    \node[anchor=south west] 
      at (O) {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm,symmetry=h]{35}};
    \node[anchor=south east] 
      at (O-|P)  {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm,symmetry=h]{36}};
  },
  secondextra={%
    \node[anchor=south west] 
      at (O) {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm,symmetry=h]{35}};
    \node[anchor=south east] 
      at (O-|P)  {\pgfornament[width=1.5cm,symmetry=h]{36}};
  }
]{mybox}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\begin{mybox}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge დედის  ამაგს
    \end{center}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{ბოროტსა  სძლევს.}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    დედის  ამაგს,\\
    დედის  ვარამს.\\
    ვერ  გაიგებს,\\
    შვილი  მანამ,\\
    სანამ  დედა\\
    ცოცხალია,\\
    თავის  გრძნობებს,\\
    გულში  მალავს.\\
    ვით  მებაღე\\
    ნერგის  ნაზარდს,\\
    შეჰხარის  და\\
    აწევს  ჯაფას.\\
    დედის  გულიც\\
    ასე  არის,\\
    ელოდება,\\
    შვილის  გაზრდას.\\
    რა  წვალებით,\\
    გაგვზრდის  დედა.\\
    ვით  მერცხალი,\\
    თავის  ბარტყებს.\\
    შემოგვისხავს,\\
    ცივ  ზამთარში.\\
    თბილ  ბუხართან,\\
    თავის  ანცებს.\\
    მოგვიყვება,\\
    წითელქუდას.\\
    ამირანის,\\
    გმირულ  ამბებს.\\
    რომ   კეთილი,\\
    ბოროტსა  სძლევს.\\
    და  სიკეთე,\\
    გულს  არ  ავნებს.\\
    იქ  ბუნება,\\
    ვერ  უშველის.\\
    თუ  მშობელი,\\
    აღზრდას  აკლებს.\\
    თუ  პატარა,\\
    ვერ  გაზარდე.\\
    დიდობაში,\\
    შენვე  გავნებს.\\[0.5cm]

        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---ვუძღვნი  ყველა  დედას,  პირველ  რიგში  ჩემ  საკუთარ  დედას.}
    \end{verse}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! thank you very much. I cannot accept this as an answer because Karlkoeller was closer to what I asked but this is my favorite answer :)

Comment: I have a problem though: `File 'pgfornament.sty' not found.`

Comment: @MenelaosVergis: you will find it here: http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html

Comment: @HarishKumar: I have used pgfornament but now i have an other problem: `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'Maroon'.`

Comment: @HarishKumar: Wow! Excellent! Grats

Comment: `tikz` won again... :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller Oh No! I am sorry :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the `\curlyframe` command works with vertical boxes and if the contents of the box goes over the page, you lose part of your text.

Here I define two new commands `\curlyframestart` and `\curlyframeend` which take an optional argument to be used respectively before and after the contents you want in the frame.

```
\newcommand{\curlyframestart}[1][1]{%
  \hbox to#1\textwidth{\ding\char'105\hfill\char'106}%
  \vskip-\baselineskip%
}

\newcommand{\curlyframeend}[1][1]{%
  \vskip-\baselineskip%
  \hbox to#1\textwidth{\ding\char'110\hfill\char'107}
}
```

Note that the optional argument is to set the horizontal box to a suitable value, in your case `1.1` seems the right value (the default is `1`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

% twoside, openright
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% removes numbering of sectioning units

%\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{niceframe}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}


\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\linespread{1.05}

\title{A book title}
\author{xxx}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\curlyframestart}[1][1]{%
  \hbox to#1\textwidth{\ding\char'105\hfill\char'106}%
  \vskip-\baselineskip%
}

\newcommand{\curlyframeend}[1][1]{%
  \vskip-\baselineskip%
  \hbox to#1\textwidth{\ding\char'110\hfill\char'107}
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\curlyframestart[1.1]
    \begin{center}
    \Huge დედის  ამაგს
    \end{center}

    \settowidth{\versewidth}{ბოროტსა  სძლევს.}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
    დედის  ამაგს,\\
    დედის  ვარამს.\\
    ვერ  გაიგებს,\\
    შვილი  მანამ,\\
    სანამ  დედა\\
    ცოცხალია,\\
    თავის  გრძნობებს,\\
    გულში  მალავს.\\
    ვით  მებაღე\\
    ნერგის  ნაზარდს,\\
    შეჰხარის  და\\
    აწევს  ჯაფას.\\
    დედის  გულიც\\
    ასე  არის,\\
    ელოდება,\\
    შვილის  გაზრდას.\\
    რა  წვალებით,\\
    გაგვზრდის  დედა.\\
    ვით  მერცხალი,\\
    თავის  ბარტყებს.\\
    შემოგვისხავს,\\
    ცივ  ზამთარში.\\
    თბილ  ბუხართან,\\
    თავის  ანცებს.\\
    მოგვიყვება,\\
    წითელქუდას.\\
    ამირანის,\\
    გმირულ  ამბებს.\\
    რომ   კეთილი,\\
    ბოროტსა  სძლევს.\\
    და  სიკეთე,\\
    გულს  არ  ავნებს.\\
    იქ  ბუნება,\\
    ვერ  უშველის.\\
    თუ  მშობელი,\\
    აღზრდას  აკლებს.\\
    თუ  პატარა,\\
    ვერ  გაზარდე.\\
    დიდობაში,\\
    შენვე  გავნებს.\\

        \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---ვუძღვნი  ყველა  დედას,  პირველ  რიგში  ჩემ  საკუთარ  დედას.}
    \end{verse}
\curlyframeend[1.1]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]