# Best way to have a tikz-framed block of fully formatted text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

I am looking for an elegant way to frame text with ornamental frames, like in the image below. I can produce these in `tikz` using the `pgfornament` package, and I can technically add text inside as a label of a `node`, but as far as I can tell, this has limitations. Namely, trying to add a `chapter` or `section` declaration inside the `node` produces errors.

Currently I am drawing the full frame below the text and shifting it up via negative `vspace`, but this is very hacky and it feels weird. Any better suggestions for having fully-formatted text, including `section`s and the such, inside a `tikzpicture`?

EDIT: Bonus: how would you go about doing the same thing in a `multicols` environment, framing the whole page but not breaking the `multicols`?

[image: Text in frame]

Comment: A you aware of [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)?

Comment: @DG' I was not, and that solves some other issues I have, but I don't think it solves the customizable elaborate borders I can get with `pgfornament`

Comment: An example with `tcolorbox` and `pgfornament`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162113/1952